# jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named PySpark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Am trying to execute Jupyter notebook from command line. Am currently using the docker image provided in below link

https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook

When i try to execute below in command line it fails.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=PySpark --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=3600 --execute notebooks/sample-notebook.ipynb
```

Below is the error message

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook notebooks/sample-notebook.ipynb to notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 340, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 510, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 481, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 410, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 179, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 197, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/notebook.py", line 32, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = super(NotebookExporter, self).from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 139, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 316, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 403, in preprocess
    with self.setup_preprocessor(nb, resources, km=km):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 345, in setup_preprocessor
    self.km, self.kc = self.start_new_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 291, in start_new_kernel
    km.start_kernel(extra_arguments=self.extra_arguments, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 301, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 254, in pre_start_kernel
    kernel_cmd = self.format_kernel_cmd(extra_arguments=extra_arguments)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 178, in format_kernel_cmd
    cmd = self.kernel_spec.argv + extra_arguments
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 84, in kernel_spec
    self._kernel_spec = self.kernel_spec_manager.get_kernel_spec(self.kernel_name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 235, in get_kernel_spec
    raise NoSuchKernel(kernel_name)
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named PySpark
```

Comment: is `PySpark` listed if you run `jupyter kernelspec list`?